# Use product sku in woocommerce as the permalink url

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

I am working on the woocommerce site for a large company with thousands of products. Each product has a unique numeric sku in its details, such as 9000067. Each product also has an insanely long name, meaning our permalinks are extremely long.

I'd like to set the permalinks to use the product sku as the url if that's possible, so the urls for each product become something as basic as company.com/product/90000067.

Is that doable?

Comment: There actually is a plugin [link]https://wordpress.org/plugins/sku-shortlink-for-woocommerce/

Comment: I tried that and it did the job, but all the pages were 404.

Comment: Any clue on why? Have you used that plugin?

Comment: I have not used the plugin, however I assume it simply does url rewriting "onthefly".  Please post a sample of the URL that is producing the 404. Sometimes it's just a simple extra trailing slash

Comment: I think I got it figured out - thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

This is made possible with the awesome [Premmerce Permalink Manager](https://premmerce.com/woocommerce-permalink-manager/) plugin, you can replace the product slug with the SKU in the product permalink and turn on URL rewriting to redirect the slug permalink to the SKU one.